# Efficient way to convert multiset to set

Tags: c++, set, multiset

Is there an efficient way to convert multiset to set, instead of loop all elements in multimap, test if set has the element, if yes insert if not continue? For multiset and set, I prefer using stock C++ containers, but other language implementation are also OK.

Comment: Why not just insert all elements? `set` itself will prevent duplicates, you don't have to. Other than that, unless you keep track of duplicates beforehand, no, there is no more efficient way to insert all element than to insert all elements.

Answer (score 3):

`std::set<T> new_set(multiset_obj.begin(), multiset_obj.end();` should do the trick. Let the language and container requirements be your friend.

Comment: Need a close parenthesis at the end

Answer (score 3):

You can create a set from an existing multiset

```
template<typename T>
set<T> SetFromMultiset(multiset<T> const &ms)
{
    set<T> ret(ms.cbegin(), ms.cend())
    return ret;
}
```

I'm supposing you are using c++11, so there is no overhead in returning a container by value, only a move operation (even though this is a case where RVO would apply)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that above answers are most efficient.

Items in multiset is ordered, but the constructor of set probably doesn't know that, and will perform a lookup on every insert.

Try this:

```
std::set<T> result;
for (auto item: the_multiset) {
    result.insert(result.end(), item);
}
```

But it is still not perfect because it will walk through all duplicate values one by one, and if there are a large number of duplicate values, it wastes time. Because it is a multiset, so the internal data can just be something like a `map<key, count>,` and it should allow developer to go directly to next different value. I hope this can happen in future C++.